# Eclipse: rerun the last gradle task just using keyboard

Tags: eclipse, gradle, keyboard, mouse, buildship

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304867/hotkey-for-run-last-task-for-eclipse-gradle-sts-plugin) was me.  With the "Gradle STS" Eclipse plugin.  In the end I managed to find an answer. IIRC, you went Run --> External tools... something something.  Haven't looked at these things for a month or two so I've forgotten.

I recently reinstalled Eclipse, and was aware that we're told "Gradle STS" is on the way out and really quite contemptible... all the people at the bleeding edge are switching to Buildship like crazy.

Fair enough, OK, I shall yield to this intense pressure to drop Gradle STS ... but how might I launch a task (even the last task) not having to use the mouse?  I ***HATE***...  :-( being forced to use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

"Workaround" (hardly brilliant): Ctrl-F7 will take you from window to window (Ctrl-F6 just navigates through editors).

So you can arrange your Gradle Tasks window in such a way that you can still see your console window ... and then Ctrl-F7 to where you want to go.

"Workaround" (slightly better): Ctrl-Shift-L twice to get to the "customise hotkey" dialog.  Give a key binding to "Show View (Gradle Tasks)".

Would welcome any answers which involve use of menus...